# Disable operations outside user's home directory with chroot jail?

Tags: users, chroot, vsftpd

I'm trying to restrict a user to a specific directory called `gclegal` using a chroot jail. I've uncommented the line in the `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Created a new user called `kg`:

```
$ sudo groupadd xenomai
$ sudo useradd -d /var/www/html/gclegal -g xenomai kg
$ sudo passwd kg
```

With this configuration I'm able to login through vsftpd with `kg` user but I'm also able to browse back to parent directories and modify them until `/var/www/html`.

How can I disable all operations outside the home of the user (`/var/www/html/gclegal`)?

Answer (score 8):

Working from the `vsftpd` version 2.2.2, there are two options for keeping users in a `chroot` jail:

- `chroot_list_enable`

Just add users to the `chroot` list e.g. (`/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list`) that you want placing in a `chroot jail`.

- `chroot_local_user`

This will place all local users in a `chroot` jail, **however**, if this is set then the `chroot_list` becomes a list of users who **DO NOT** go in a `chroot jail`.

Therefore check your list does not contain user `kg` if you have `chroot_local_user=YES` configured.

Obviously restart the `vsftpd` daemon after making configuration changes.

*Excert from man vsftpd.conf*

```
   chroot_list_enable
          If activated, you may provide a list of local users who are placed in a chroot() jail  in  their  home  directory  upon  login.  The  meaning  is  slightly  different  if
          chroot_local_user  is set to YES. In this case, the list becomes a list of users which are NOT to be placed in a chroot() jail.  By default, the file containing this list
          is /etc/vsftpd/chroot_list, but you may override this with the chroot_list_file setting.

          Default: NO

   chroot_local_user
          If set to YES, local users will be (by default) placed in a chroot() jail in their home directory after login.  Warning: This option has security implications, especially
          if  the  users  have  upload permission, or shell access. Only enable if you know what you are doing.  Note that these security implications are not vsftpd specific. They
          apply to all FTP daemons which offer to put local users in chroot() jails.

          Default: NO
```

---

I have configured vsftpd to `chroot` users and these are the `/etc/vsftpd.conf` settings that I used (`Ubuntu 14.04`):

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

**NOTE:**
Ensure `/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list` or `/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list` are empty.

---

Once you get it working, if you want to keep track of `ftp` logins, then you can set `session_support=YES` and these should then apprear using the `last` command:

```
username   vsftpd:12025 IP address     Tue Oct 14 14:05 - 14:10  (00:05)
username   vsftpd:12011 IP address     Tue Oct 14 14:04 - 14:05  (00:00)
```

NOTE - utmp and wtmp support is only provided with PAM enabled builds.

Comment: Thanks, 
`vsftpd -v
vsftpd: version 3.0.2` I've just the `chroot_list_enable=YES`. I've created the file in /etc/vsftpd/chroot.list and added the kg user. I'm still able to browse back and modify the html folder.

Comment: @narutov6 - To confirm, if you have `chroot_list_enable=YES`, then the list should contain users who you do NOT want `chrooting`. Why dont you try setting `chroot_list_enable=YES`, `chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list`, `chroot_list_enable=NO` and keep kg in your chroot_list, restart vsftpd and check again. P.S. What OS are you running?

Comment: Same behavior with `chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list` and corresponding file set up. I've tried with `chroot_list_enable=YES` `chroot_list_enable=NO`. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @narutov6 - I have just got this working on `Ubuntu 14.04` using your user settings and directories and updated the Answer with my settings. I had to add the `allow_writeable_chroot` setting to disable the latest security feature.

Comment: I have your same config file. If I connect with `kg` user with filezilla, the `/var/www/html/gclegal` folder is opened but I am able to browse back to `/var/www/html` and transfer file to it...same problem as before.

Comment: Sorry for the basic question, but you are connecting via ftp port 21, not sftp port 22?

Comment: I am connecting via SFTP to another port. Connections via port 22 are blocked. I was looking for the port configuration but I couldn't find the `listen_port` line. Do you know where can I find it? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Ok if I switch back the connection port to 22 in the sshd_config it works fine. I'm not able to transfer files outsite the chrooted user home which is perfect! But how can I get the same result using the connection port 223?

Comment: Ok, that is why I asked my last question, `vsftpd` is very secure ftp daemon. not sftp daemon. You can encrypt it with ssl, however, you need to use the ftp protocol to connect to it, not the sftp protocol. so you should be using ftp at port 21. Obviously you can check the port it is listening on with `netstat -an`.

Comment: Now I'am able to connect via SFTP with chrooted `kg` user and restrictions on the folder work great. So this means that I'm not using the configuration in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`? I'm a bit confused...

Comment: There is a way to use `sftp`, however, I thought you had to enable ssl in the `vsftpd.conf` plus add settings into your `ssh` config, If that is what you want to do then follow these [instructions](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04-vsftpd/).

Answer (score -1):

I set selinux to `permissive` and restarted `vsftpd.service`, which fixed the problem.